# Have either of the Jennings used the "rub your thumb" technique in previous episodes?

Tags: the-americans

In S05E02 of *The Americans*, Phillip and Elizabeth teach their daughter, Paige, a technique to use if she is in distress and it feels like she's about to disclose her parents' real identity to her boyfriend:

```
Rub her forefinger and thumb together and think about her parents.
```

Have either of the Jennings parents used this technique themselves in previous episodes?

Comment: if it has been used, it was not shown on screen, nor references in a particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

No, they've not used that technique.  But then again, Phillip and Elizabeth are experienced and well-trained spies.  I would think their need to use such a crutch disappeared long ago.  I would also think that to lie convincingly, keeping calm, and manage stress would've been addressed during their training.

Anyway it looks like a post-hypnotic trigger - probably some sort of auto-hypnosis - so they may use another (more discrete) trigger... and after using it enough times, you really don't need the trigger - it's enough to just *imagine* using it (in your mind)... or with enough practice, even just willing the result (eg. to stay calm).